# Android Material Date Picker Date Format

Tags: java, android, datepicker, android-datepicker, material-components-android

I'm using material date picker in my app to select dates. Below is my code.

```
MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
    builder.setSelection(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
    builder.setTitleText(getString(R.string.selectDate));
    final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = builder.build();

    btn_pickDate(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"DATE_PICKER");
        }
    });
    
    materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {
            startDate.setText(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());
        }
    });
```

when I select a date, the date is returned in **dd MMM yyyy** in device one and **MMM dd, yyyy** in device two.

I need the date to be returned in same format (Ex: **dd MMM yyyy**) across all devices. How to achieve this in material date picker.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `addOnPositiveButtonClickListener` listener returns the selected date as Long value. In this way you have a **long value** and not a String.

You can use:

```
    MaterialDatePicker<Long> materialDatePicker = builder.build();
    
    materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onPositiveButtonClick(Long selection) {
           //....
           Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
           calendar.setTimeInMillis(selection);
           SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MM dd");
           String formattedDate  = format.format(calendar.getTime());
        }
    });
```

In kotlin:

```
materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
    val utc = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    utc.timeInMillis = it
    val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val formatted: String = format.format(utc.time)        
}
```

Comment: I think the question is also about formatting it consistently across all devices. Depending on the Locale, the time zone of the device, a `Long` time is not so helpful: in particular, the user is supposed to pick a *date* and the API returns a *time*, it requires quite some processing to get the right date and format, see the answer with the offset calculation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the MaterialPicker date format then use the below code this code is working for me.

```
MaterialDatePicker<Long> materialDatePicker=materialDateBuilder.build();
materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onPositiveButtonClick(Long selection) {
            // Get the offset from our timezone and UTC.
            TimeZone timeZoneUTC = TimeZone.getDefault();
            // It will be negative, so that's the -1
            int offsetFromUTC = timeZoneUTC.getOffset(new Date().getTime()) * -1;
            // Create a date format, then a date object with our offset
            SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
            Date date = new Date(selection + offsetFromUTC);

            mEt_last_date_to_apply.setText(simpleFormat.format(date));
        }
    });
```

Comment: I think it's the best answer. Following [a comment on a similar Github issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/653#issuecomment-554538469), I think some cleaner code would be to set the timezone on the SimpleDateFormat directly: 

`SimpleDateFormat simpleFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);`
*`simpleFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));`*
`mEt_last_date_to_apply.setText(simpleFormat.format(Date(selection)));
`

Answer (score 2):

You should use [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat) to format date according to your choice.

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog view, int Year, int Month, int Day) {

    Calendar selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance().set(Year,Month,Day);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String formatedDate = formatter.format(selectedDate );
    //to sting desired format date
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, formatedDate , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Happy Coding !

Comment: Hey, your code brings the following error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date`

Comment: I think your answer is for DatePicker Dialog and not **Material Date Picker**. Please check my code. In my code, `materialDatePicker.getHeaderText()` will return the selected date.

Comment: I might have slipped there .. but you can use  `SimpleDateFormat` there as well ...

Comment: `DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");  
                DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  
                Date date = originalFormat.parse(materialDatePicker.getHeaderText());  
                attn_date.setText(targetFormat.format(date));` We need to know the original date format (i.e.,the selected date from datepicker dialog)  in order to change the date to target format. And my problem is, the original format varies across devices (Ex: MMM dd, yyyy in some devices and dd MM yyyy in some devices).

Comment: hmm well... `new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy")` is the format you to format into. you provide your desired format in `new SimpleDateFormat("your desired format")` and `targetFormat.format(date)` will give you the result.

Comment: you simply need a date or calendar object to pass to `format(date)`

Comment: Actually this works when I know the original format. The problem is I don't know what the original format is. The original format varies across devices.

Comment: well I might repro it, but that will be tomorrow, I'll update you

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

```
   val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
    builder.setTitleText("Select a Date")
    val picker = builder.build()
    tv_rw_startDate.setOnClickListener {
        picker.show(activity?.supportFragmentManager!!, picker.toString())
        picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
            calendar.time = Date(it)
            tv_rw_startDate.text = "${calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)}/ " +
                    "${calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1}/${calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)}"
        }
    }
```